# Qt6 android application - very large build size

Tags: android, qt6

After the migration of the project from Qt5 to Qt6, the size of the project build for android has increased many times. The main library (*.so) of the project began to occupy 700 MB instead of the previous 16 MB.

Maybe I need to specify some build parameters to get a size comparable to the previous one?

when build, there is such a message:

```
> Task :stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libMyApp_arm64-v8a.so, libQt6Core5Compat_arm64-v8a.so, …
```

Answer (score 0):

it was necessary to notice these lines in the logs and install the specified NDK version.

```
C/C++: Because no explicit NDK was requested, the default version [21.4.7075529] for this Android Gradle Plugin will be used
C/C++: Folder D:\develop\AndroidSDK\ndk\21.4.7075529 does not exist. Ignoring.
```

In my case, this is **ndk\21.4.7075529**

The size of the apk has been reduced to 30 MB. And before the problem was solved, it was more than 300 MB.